# Laravel Eloquent counting relatationship and order it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm sure I am missing something painfully obvious, I have been trying to get all of the likes that belong to a Freestyle, count them and display them in a side bar, I would like to be able to order the sidebar by highest to lowest amount of likes on each freestyle.

So far I am returning the following:

```
 <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span>joshua</span><span>1</span></li>
 <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span>lee</span><span>5</span></li>
 <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span>josh</span><span>5</span></li>
 <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span></span><span>3</span></li>
 <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span></span><span>1</span></li>
```

As you can see, i am getting the freestlers name and the amount of likes tied to that freestyle but I have no way of ordering them when I get the data like the following:

```
Blade template (Messy)
ul class="top-compet-list">
    @foreach($freestyles as $freestyle)
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt=""><span>{{$freestyle->users['Username']}}</span><span>{{$freestyle->likes->count()}}</span></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

Freestyle variable: $view->with('freestyles', Freestyle::has('likes', '>=', '1')->get());
```

I also took the query scope approach, and while I could use the raw queries to join and grab all of the likes and count them I had an issue when it came to presenting the data in a foreach of my freestyles. I felt asif I was fighting the framework too.

```
My make shift query scope:
    public function scopeFindTheLikes($query)
{
    return $query->join('Likes', 'Freestyle.id', '=', 'Likes.freestyleID')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as like_count, freestyleID'))
        ->groupBy('freestyleID')
        ->orderBy('like_count', 'desc')
        ->get();
}
```

Any help is appreciated on the correct way to do this, I'm sure I am passing the data through in an incorrect way or I need to do more. Thanks all!

Comment: first thing is what error you got?Another is try use an field name like table.id for count

Comment: No error Imitaz, I have the data returning I just cannot sort through it with the approach I am taking above. The query scope was just there to show how I was utilizing it, i am no longer using it